# Atmospheric pressure in a closed container

Tags: homework-and-exercises, pressure, fluid-statics

it's my first post here but I just have a quick question regarding my fluid mechanics assignment.

There's an inverted manometer setup like in the photo which is a closed system. It's given me atmospheric pressure reading at point M and wants me to figure out gauge pressure at point N. I'm fine with all the calculations but not sure whether I should subtract 1atm from the final answer or not.[image]

Comment: Where does it say in the problem statement that there is atmospheric pressure at M?  If the absolute pressure at N is 70 kPa, what is the gauge pressure at N?  Once this is known, you can work entirely in terms of. gauge pressures.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should subtract 1 atm from your result.  Gauge pressure is the absolute pressure minus atmospheric pressure.